# How to return a derived class using only code in the base class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I was recently posed this programming problem and failed to solve it. I was asked to write a subclass that could be inherited so that the below code could function correctly. Here's the catch, the base class (I named it Party) is the only one that can contain code for Find().

```
var address = new Address("56 Main St", "Town", "AZ", "12345");
var customer = new Customer("John", "Doe", address);
var company = new Company("Town Company", address);

Customer savedCustomer = Customer.Find(customer.Id);
Company savedCompany = Company.Find(company.Id);
```

`Party` is hidden. `Customer` and `Company` both inherit it.

How could I have caused Party to return Customer and Company when called from one of those classes? I was told it's possible using generics but that I can't change the calls to look like `Find<Company>(customer.Id)`. However, all the resources I examined say you can't return derived types from a base class.

EDIT: I solved it by have `Customer.Find()` and `Company.Find()` call `Party.partyFind()` and then cast the result to their type. I submitted the solution along with the explanation:

> I tried to keep the Find functionality in the base class as much in
>   the base class as possible but I wasn't sure how to return derived
>   types from a single base class without generics (which would require
>   modifying the test code anyway)

I received the reply:

> You're mistaken, generics can solve this problem without modifying the
>   test code; specializing `Find` at the call site as `Find<Customer>` is not
>   allowed. You have more to learn about generics.

Comment: To me, this question seems explicitly allowed by the help center's saying eligible topics include *a specific programming problem*.

Comment: Where is the Party? (pun intended). I find it hard to reason about base classes if I don't have everything on the table.

Comment: If you can't make `Find` generic, you have to rely on casting and hope that it returns an object of the correct type.

Comment: @rene I edited my answer.

Comment: Do you really need to use inheritance or are you just assuming? Seems to me `Party` just needs a generic method : `public T Find<T>(int id) { }`

Comment: @Crowcoder The spec said it must be a sub class inherited by `Company` and `Customer` and I couldn't modify `Find()` to `Find<T>()`.

Comment: Are you sure that Find is a static method? This question is somewhat nonsensical if it is.

Comment: @Jamiec I did not realize that. The methods are indeed static. I don't know how this requirement could possibly have been met then but they said they'd filled the position so I guess someone is smarter than I am.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at your update, what the person was talking about was probably specializing `Party`:

```
public class Party<T>
{
    public static T Find(int id)
    {
         ...
    }
}

public class Customer : Party<Customer>{}
public class Company : Party<Company>{}
```

This can then indeed call `Find` statically on derived classes without passing the generic type to the `Find` method explicitly.

```
var cust = Customer.Find(1); // returns instance of Customer
var comp = Company.Find(2); // returns instance of Company
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/GPDFI94766

Comment: Curses! I bet you're right. But how does it work? Could you make that method static and have it inherit through some virtue of generics?

Comment: Add `static` to `Find` definition. Then `Customer.Find` and `Company.Find` will be valid calls.