# c# generic base class method return the type of the derived class

Tags: c#, generics

I want a base class method to return the type of the derived class.
according to [Can a Base Class Method return the type of the derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122632/can-a-base-class-method-return-the-type-of-the-derived-class)

base class

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
}
```

extension

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static U Project<U, T>(this U node)
     where U : BaseClass<T>
  {
     // do something
     return node;
  }
}
```

child class

```
public class ChildClass: BaseClass<string>
{
}
```

usage

```
var child= new ChildClass();
var projected = child.Project(); // error: can't infer type T
var projected = child.Project<ChildClass, string>(); // ok
```

**Question:**
 One solution is [How to return a derived class using only code in the base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35607581/how-to-return-a-derived-class-using-only-code-in-the-base-class), but class inherit from child class won't work.
 How can I use method without specifying T?

Comment: You cannot do that with out providing T. I would encourage you to examine how List<T> is designed.  It maybe helpful to have a non generic interface to work with as well.

Comment: @rahicks thanks a lot to help. I have updated my code and question, but why can't compiler get T from U?

Comment: How is `PolygonNode` defined?

Comment: @ja72 thanks a lot to help. that's not important. Basiclly this is a question about "generic base class method return the type of the derived class
", I have deleted interface and updated my question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20842231/380384

Comment: As long as the extension method is generic (i.e. `Project<U, T>()`) then you need to supply the parameters. Your only hope is if the parameters are inferred from the arguments.

Comment: @ja72 Yes you are right. Because if I must supply the type parameters, I'll just let it be simply inherit. but I think it's weird to supply type or prop's type when return type is the same as instance itself.

Comment: Is there a way to make the node type `T` the only parameter? Rolling your own collection classes (as in `BaseClass<T>`) breaks the nice OOP features of C# because in needs to be strongly typed. For example `IEnumerable<T> Project(this IEnumerable<T> list)`

Comment: @ja72 Good idea. But maybe a little perfectionism, if so, I may just use `public BaseClass<T> Project2()` in `BaseClass` and use `var prj3 = child.Project2() as ChildClass;` . It seems that It's hard to find solution as elegant as other questions' refered in my question. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need to provide all the piping to clone objects manually and let the compiler decide the correct overload.

```
public interface ICSGNode<T> where T:ICSGNode<T>
{
    T Clone();
    void Invert();
}
public class NodeList<T> : Collection<T>
    where T : ICSGNode<T> 

{
    public NodeList(params T[] items) : base(items) { }
    public static implicit operator NodeList<T>(T[] array) { return new NodeList<T>(array); }

    public T[] Clone() { return this.Select((n) => n.Clone()).ToArray(); }
}

public class PolygonNode : ICSGNode<PolygonNode>, ICloneable
{
    public PolygonNode()
    {
        // create a unique object
    }
    public PolygonNode(PolygonNode other)
    {
        // create a copy
    }

    public void Invert()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public PolygonNode Clone() { return new PolygonNode(this); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }

}

public class PolygonList : NodeList<PolygonNode>, ICloneable
{
    public PolygonList(params PolygonNode[] items) : base(items) { }
    public static implicit operator PolygonList(PolygonNode[] array) { return new PolygonList(array); }

    public new PolygonList Clone() { return new PolygonList(base.Clone()); }
    object ICloneable.Clone() { return Clone(); }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new PolygonList
        {
            new PolygonNode(),
            new PolygonNode(),
            new PolygonNode(),
        };
        var clone = list.Clone();
        // clone is of `PolygonList` type
    }
}
```

Tricks Used:

- Apply the `ICloneable` interface to the derived classes only.
- Overwrite the default behavior of returning `object` with a strongly typed `Clone()` method.
- Implement copy constructors that copy objects properties within the constructor only.
- Lastly avoid returning a concrete or generic collection type from any base `Clone()` method. Return an array and let the derived class assembly the strongly typed clone from the array of items.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I don't really understand what you mean. I have updated my question and given a more abstract model for my question.The relationship of inheritance can not be changed since base class has a lot other methods.

Comment: @vinsticclinton - at least try my code. Step through it and see if you understand better.

Comment: Sure, I'll try it.